# Python 3: unescape literal hex, unicode and python escapes

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, escaping

What is the proper way to do the following:

- accept any unicode string (this gets read in from a file that contains utf-8 encoded strings)
- if the string contains literal escapes (sequences) of the form \xA0\xB0 (so in Python this will show as \xA0\XB0) replace them with the actual characters or with some fallback (e.g. a space) if this is an invalid code
- if the string contains literal unicode character escapes of the form \u0008 (so in python this will show as \u0008) replace with the actual character represented by that code
- if the string contains python string escapes of the form \n or \t (so in python this will show as \n and \t), replace with the actual character represented by that code
- As a bonus, also replace all HTML entities of the form &#a0;
- all actual unicode characters should remain unchanged

Basically, something that converts back all the rubbish one sometimes gets when people have created a file in the wrong way and it now contains the literal escapes instead of the code represented by those escapes.

This has GOT to be a solved problem, but all I can find are rather clumsy and incomplete solutions.

Comment: I think you should build a parser, parsing character per character. The second point is tricky, because not all sequence are valid unicode. I do not know if it a solved problem, you have a lot of requisites, and every programmers have different way to think it. (e.g. on a configuration file, handling also the quotes, maybe the includes. And you are forgetting the `\U00012345`

Comment: `print('\xB0\xA0\xB0 ěščřžý \u0008\t\U00012345\t\U0001F5B6'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))` returns `° ° ěščřžý             ` (without the _"bonus"_) .